# Angular 2 read input file

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to understand how to use input file with Angular 2. In my example below, I would like my console to log the name of the file I have uploaded. Unfortunately, this code sends an error `Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`.

My **component.html**

```
<input 
   id="imageUpload" 
   type="file" 
   (change)="imageRun(input)"/>
```

My **component.ts**

```
imageRun(input){
    var files = input.target.files[0];
    console.log(files.name);
}
```

I am unsure if there is an Angular specific solution to this issue, as I have run into the same issue when doing this in plain javascript. I have looked over a few plain JS tutorials that all have me using the `addEventListener` method in JS, instead of assigning these triggers in HTML. But these methods, as far as I understand, do not really apply to an Angular 2 project.

For reference, here is [an example](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) of doing pretty much the same thing in plain JavaScript, and using addEventListener inside the src script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define local template variable on inpit file element & use it inside a Component.

```
<Input #myInput
   id="imageUpload" 
   type="file" 
   (change)="imageRun(myInput)"/>

imageRun(input){
    var file = myInput.files[0];
    console.log(file.name);
}
```

Comment: Doing the first one leads to `Cannot read property 'srcElement' of undefined`. Will look into the second.